# map(lambda,list) return None instead object

Tags: python, django

I want add attribute to all object (that are model instance in django) in a list. for example the list is:

```
persons = [
        {"age":"12","name":"John"},
        {"age":"10","name":"Joye"}
]
```

and we assume that i want put value of `person.age` in `person.number`and i have a new list that all of person have new attribute `number` so my function is :

```
new_persons_list=list(map(lambda person:setattr(person, 'number', person.age), persons))
```

but the output is `[None,None]` while i expect that output be:

```
persons = [
        {"age":12,"name":"John","number":12},
        {"age":10,"name":"Joye","number":10}
]
```

if possible i don't like to add new function in `map` and i want use lambda.what is the problem?thank you

Comment: `setattr(..)` will return `None`, since it does not calculate something, it changes something.

Comment: The above should raise an `AttributeError`, not return `None`s. It looks like your smaple data is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**: with the above sample code, it will raise an `AttributeError`, since a dictionary has no `.age` attribute. I assume that you use Django objects instead which indeed have attributes if you defined a field.

A `setattr(..)` function updates an object. Most functions that update something do not return something (this is not per se true, but for a lot of functions, that holds).

So your list is simply obtaining the results of the `setattr` call. We can circumvent the problem with:

```
new_persons_list=list(map(lambda person: setattr(person, 'number', person.age) or person, persons))
```

But it makes more sense that you just use a `for` loop here to update the objects:

```
for person in persons:
    person.number = person.age
```

Comment: thank you for explanation Mr.Van Onsem . i do that with `map(function,list)` simply 
 that function is `setattr(badge, 'create_date', badge.assign_date)
        return badge`. but as i never using lambda i want learn how it work exactly an now the first time i can use it in my project so i want try my best to use `lambda` because its very clean and small code need.

Comment: @mehdi: the lambda is `lambda i: setattr(badge 'create_date', badge.assign_date) or badge`. A lambda does not have a `return` since you could see it as a function with an implicit return.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy, so use:

```
new_persons_list=list(map(lambda person:{**person.to_dict(), "number": person.age}, persons))
```

Comment: that is good idea but error appear `'person' object is not subscriptable` . then i i try to fix it to `new_persons_list=list(map(lambda person:{**person, "number": person.age}, persons))` and new error appear :`'person' object is not a mapping` .

Comment: this object are model instance so i think we need to use `setattr` in lambda.am i right?

Comment: @mehdi you second comment is incorrect, however can you give me what `print(type(persons[0]))` is?

Comment: @mehdi Does my code work now? give me `print(type(persons[0]))`s if it doesn't work

Comment: it's not working .the error is `'person' object has no attribute 'to_dict'` . and when i run `print(type(persons[0]))` the output is `<class 'type'>`

Comment: @mehdi How about `print(type(persons))`

Comment: here is output Mr.U10-Forward `<class 'list'>`